# mvn clean install ERROR: cannot find symbol symbol: class BASE64Encoder, location: package sun.misc M1 Mac

Tags: java, maven, build, base64

I'm trying to setup a legacy java application so I can reverse engineer it. However, when building it via `mvn clean install` from the mac terminal (I've tried Rossetta and normal), I get this error:

```
[ERROR] /Users/danieljohnson/Documents/manage/og/gems/ems/src/main/java/com/ems/hvac/utils/CryptographyUtil.java:[34,16] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BASE64Decoder
  location: package sun.misc
[ERROR] /Users/danieljohnson/Documents/manage/og/gems/ems/src/main/java/com/ems/hvac/utils/CryptographyUtil.java:[35,16] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BASE64Encoder
  location: package sun.misc
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.631 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-23T12:43:34-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project ems: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /Users/danieljohnson/Documents/manage/og/gems/ems/src/main/java/com/ems/hvac/utils/CryptographyUtil.java:[34,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class BASE64Decoder
[ERROR]   location: package sun.misc
[ERROR] /Users/danieljohnson/Documents/manage/og/gems/ems/src/main/java/com/ems/hvac/utils/CryptographyUtil.java:[35,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class BASE64Encoder
[ERROR]   location: package sun.misc
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project ems: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
```

output of `java -version`:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_345"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.64.0.19-CA-macos-aarch64) (build 1.8.0_345-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.64.0.19-CA-macos-aarch64) (build 25.345-b01, mixed mode)
```

I'm aware the `sun.misc` package is deprecated and should be replaced by `java.util.Base64`. However, that's not a plug and play solution, so I would like to get it working with `sun.misc` if possible.

Comment: *However, that's not a plug and play solution* I don't understand what you mean by that. It's the *correct* solution

Comment: I'm asking if it's possible to use sun.misc on Java 8, and if not, is the only way to use sun.misc to downgrade to Java 7?

Comment: Try compiling with Java 7 or 6

Answer (score 0):

If you dont' see sun.misc then you will unfortunately need to make minor code changes to use the new library

Comment: That's not an option. I need to change my Java version/jdk to make this work. I need to figure out which jdk I can use to make it work on my M1 MAC

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should change the code to use java.util.Base64 instead. It is time to pay the technical debt.

If you cannot do that then get the Java version it was written for. This is not recommended!  Java 7 can be downloaded from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase7-archive-downloads.html

Comment: That's not an option. I need to change my Java version/jdk to make this work. I need to figure out which jdk I can use to make it work on my M1 MAC.

Comment: Can you add code? Then write the class yourself (and have it wrap the new class). If you cannot, then find and use the Java it was written with. Java 7 is very much end-of-life so you probably need to go into the Oracle archives.